# MySQL count and list the occurrence using like from another table

Tags: mysql, procedure, sql-like

I have two tables like this:

```
cars                            users
-------------------------      ---------------------------
| car    | description   |     | name   | car_owned      |
-------------------------      ---------------------------
| BMW    | Good Choice   |     | abcd   | BMW, nano      |
| Ferrari| better choice |     | efgh   | Ferrari, BMW   |
| nano   | with in budget|     | ijkl   | nano           |
--------------------------     | mnop   | nano           |
                               ---------------------------
```

I am trying to create a procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `car_count`()
BEGIN
SELECT `cars`.`car`, `users`.count(*) FROM `cars`, `users` WHERE `users`.`car_owned`
                       LIKE CONCAT('%',`cars`.`car` , '%') ;.
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I need something like this:

```
----------------------
| car     | count(*) |
----------------------
| BMW     | 2        |
| Ferrari | 1        |
| nano    | 3        |
----------------------
```

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in a single column! Can you change your table structure?

Comment: yes i can change it.  do i need to another add another table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another table. How about:

```
users table
--------------   
| id  |  name
--------------
| 1   |  abc 
| 2   |  def
| 3   |  ghi


cars table                  
--------------------------------   
| id  |  name    | description   
--------------------------------
| 1   |  BMW     | Good Choice   
| 2   |  Ferrari | better choice 
| 3   |  nano    | with in budget


user_cars table
------------------
user_id  |  car_id
------------------
1        |   1
1        |   3
2        |   2
2        |   1
....
```

And then to get the count of users having each car you can do

```
select c.name, count(u.id) as owned_count
from cars c
left join user_cars uc on uc.car_id = c.id
left join users u on uc.user_id = u.id
group by c.name
```

Comment: But the problem i am afraid of is.. if someone own 100 cars and if there is 100 numbers of someone... Then leading to addtional 10000 rows ... in my actual DB there is every one own atlest 2 to 3 cars.... there nearly 10000 user (currently)...

Comment: So? A DB can easily handle millions of records and this is the way to go. Trust me. With proper indexes this should return data in milliseconds.

Comment: i will go with u man...  I know always need to use normalized DB.. but lack of experience with DB pulls me back...

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `car_count`()
BEGIN
SELECT `car`, count(*) FROM `cars` JOIN `users` ON FIND_IN_SET(car,REPLACE(car_owned,' ',''))>0
GROUP BY car
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```